# How to debug/verify `--exclude-from` matching file for `tar`?

Tags: tar, wildcards

Command `tar` has an option `--exclude-from`:

```
   -X, --exclude-from=FILE
          Exclude files matching patterns listed in FILE.
```

How can I list all files, or roots of completely ignored folders, which match patterns in a `FILE`.

I'm making a script to backup my home directory, and I wouldn't like to accidentally ignore something important.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking. Do you want to match the contents of the tar file that may match the patterns in `FILE`, or any files on the system (under your home directory) that match patterns in `FILE`?

Comment: I want to know what will be ignored/excluded. Therefore, I want to match everything on the system that match patterns in `FILE`.

Answer (score 2):

Some `tar` commands will super-optimise what they do if you are tarring to `/dev/null`, so for example

```
tar cvf /dev/null . >/tmp/a
```

will create a list of all the files in `.` without actually reading any data. On my 10G home it took 3 seconds, about the same as a `find`.

So you could do the above, and then the same thing with your exclude list into `/tmp/b` and then do a `diff` between them to see what you lose.

Alternatively, pipe each output through `sort` as well, then use `comm -3 /tmp/a /tmp/b` to get just the excluded files.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read -r pattern; do
    printf 'Pattern: "%s"\n' "$pattern"
    echo 'Matches:'
    find . -path "$pattern" -print
done <patterns
```

This will take each pattern from the file `patterns` and report what names in the current directory matches it.

Comment: Doesn't `tar` apply these patterns recursivel?. Ie. if exclude `FILE` contains `*.o`, then the `tar` will exclude all `*.o` files, including `*.o` files in sub-directories?

Comment: @kravemir True. I've fixed it.

Comment: This doesn't work for patterns that contains a slash.

Answer (score -1):

It can be tricky as the way tar and find match patterns are not the same. But perhaps you are looking for something like this:

```
for pattern in $(cat FILE)
do
    find $HOME -path "*$pattern*"
done
```

Comment: The unquoted command substitution will expand the patterns before passing them to `find`.